# How to separate negative floating numbers which are hyphen separated using python?

Tags: python, numbers, floating

I have a list containing floating numbers (positive or negative) which are separated by a hyphen.  I would like to split them.

For example:

```
input: -76.833-106.954, -76.833--108.954
output: -76.833,106.954,-76.833,-108.954
```

I've tried `re.split(r"([-+]?\d*\.)-"`, but it doesn't work. I get an invalid literal statement for int()

Please let me know what code would you recommend me to use.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Completing @PyHunterMan's answer:

You want only one hyphen to be optional before the number indicating a negative float:

```
import re

target = '-76.833-106.954, -76.833--108.954, 83.4, -92, 76.833-106.954, 76.833--108.954'
pattern = r'(-?\d+\.\d+)' # Find all float patterns with an and only one optional hypen at the beggining (others are ignored)
match = re.findall(pattern, target)

numbers = [float(item) for item in match]
print(numbers) 

>>> [-76.833, -106.954, -76.833, -108.954, 83.4, 76.833, -106.954, 76.833, -108.954]
```

You will notice this does not catch `-92` and besides `-92` is part the Real numbers set, is not written in float format.

If you want to catch the `-92` *which is an integer* use:

```
import re

input_ = '-76.833-106.954, -76.833--108.954, 83.4, -92, 76.833-106.954, 76.833--108.954'
pattern = r'(-?\d+(\.\d+)?)'
match = re.findall(pattern, input_)

print(match)

result = [float(item[0]) for item in match]
print(result) 

>>> [-76.833, -106.954, -76.833, -108.954, 83.4, -92.0, 76.833, -106.954, 76.833, -108.954]
```